# Jenkins Pipeline script error - MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to fetch Jenkins job result using the following code:

```
pipeline {
   agent { label 'Agent_Name' }


   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            def res=build job: 'App_Build', parameters: [string(name: 'App', value: 'WindowsApp')]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However, it looks like if I add "def res=" then the job fails with the following error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed:

If I remove `def res=`, then it works fine. Also, if I keep only `def res=buid.....` line in pipeline script, then it works fine too.

How can I fix this error? I need to get the result from the App_Build job and run the pipeline in stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture the result of the `build` step, you need to put it into `script` block, e.g.

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent { label 'Agent_Name' }

   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            script {
                def res=build job: 'App_Build', parameters: [string(name: 'App', value: 'WindowsApp')]
                // do something with the result...
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```